# PHP - Object instantiation context - Odd behaviour - Is it PHP bug?

Tags: php, class, inheritance, object, instantiation

I am not asking a typical question about why some code failed, yet I am asking about why it worked.It has worked with me while coding, and I needed it to fail.

**Case**

- a base abstract class with a protected constructor declared abstract
- a parent class extends the abstract class with public constructor (Over ridding)
- a child class extends the very same abstract class with a protected constructor

  ```
    abstract class BaseClass {
      abstract protected function __construct();
    }

    class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
      protected function __construct(){
        echo 'It works';
       }
    }

    class ParentClass extends BaseClass {
      public function __construct() {
        new ChildClass();
      }
    }

    // $obj = new ChildClass(); // Will result in fatal error. Expected!

    $obj = new ParentClass(); // that works!!WHY?
  ```

**Question**

Parent class instantiates child class object, and it works!!
how come it does?
as far as I know,object cannot be instantiated if its constructor declared protected, except only internally or from within any subclasses by inheritance.

The parent class is not a subclass of the child class,it doesn't inherit a dime from it ( yet both extend the same base abstract class), so how come instantiation doesn't fail?

**EDIT**

This case only happens with an abstract BaseClass that has also an abstract constructor.If BaseClass is concerete, or if its protected constructor is not abstract, instantiation fails as expected.. is it a PHP bug?
**For my sanity, I need really an explanation to why PHP behaves this way in this very specific case.**

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm losing track of base, parent and child and which extends which. Could you add some code examples?

Comment: sure, within couple of mins I will post a code sample

Comment: My guess: The `BaseClass` is assumed to be where the constructor is defined (which it is, really), hence according to inheritance rules the `ParentClass` has access to it. Bug? Debatable. Rare edge case? Certainly.

Comment: As far as I know, it should not be instantiated since the ChildClass constructor is protected

Comment: Could you try to set private constructor instead of protected? It is interesting what is changed.

Comment: @Ahmad Yeah, but so is the original `abstract` specification of it, so arguably that's where the method is defined.

Comment: @Anthony.. instantiation fails if declared private.. but I just need explanation to why it doesn't fail either wirh protected BaseClass constructor

Comment: @deceze. I am trying to get what you are saying..sounds logical. can you explain more?

Comment: Not sure what more to say, especially since it's just my guess of what PHP "thinks". :) `BaseClass::__construct` is defined `protected`, `ChildClass::__construct` inherits that without changing it, `ParentClass::__construct` inherits from `BaseClass`, therefore `ParentClass` has access to `ChildClass::__construct`.

Comment: I understand your scenario , but why it behaves like this.. in other words. Does two irrelevant classes got access to each other just because they inherit the same BaseClass?

Comment: It's probably a special case of `abstract` methods, not of which class inherits from which. `BaseClass` **defines** the `__construct` method and its visibility, `ChildClass` merely *implements* it...

Comment: ParentClass has public ctor, so everything is fine there. Classes in the same hierarchy can access protected methods.

Comment: Clarification for the last comment: __construct's scope is BaseClass, so everything *up* the hierarchy (not "the same hierarchy") is accessible to it. When resolving protected calls, PHP always uses the lowest scope available (i.e. where the method was first defined).

Answer (score 3):

Note: the following was tested with PHP 5.3.8. Other versions may exhibit different behavior.

Since there isn't a formal specification for PHP, there isn't a way of answering this from the point of view of what *should* happen. The closest we can get is this statement about [protected](http://php.net/protected) from the PHP manual:

> Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by inherited and parent classes.

Though the member may be overridden in `ChildClass` (keeping the "protected" specifier), it was originally *declared* in `BaseClass`, so it remains visible in descendants of `BaseClass`.

In direct opposition to this interpretation, compare the behavior for a protected property:

```php
<?php
abstract class BaseClass {
    protected $_foo = 'foo';
    abstract protected function __construct();
}

class MommasBoy extends BaseClass {
    protected $_foo = 'foobar';
    protected function __construct(){
        echo __METHOD__, "\n";
    }
}

class LatchkeyKid extends BaseClass {
    public function __construct() {
        echo 'In ', __CLASS__, ":\n";
        $kid = new MommasBoy();
        echo $kid->_foo, "\n";
    }
}

$obj = new LatchkeyKid();
```

Output:

> ```
> In LatchkeyKid:
> MommasBoy::__construct
>
> Fatal error: Cannot access protected property MommasBoy::$_foo in - on line 18
> ```

Changing the abstract `__construct` to a concrete function with an empty implementation gives the desired behavior.

```php
abstract class BaseClass {
   protected function __construct() {}
}
```

However, non-magic methods are visible in relatives, whether or not they're abstract (most magic methods must be public).

```php
<?php
abstract class BaseClass {
    abstract protected function abstract_protected();
    protected function concrete() {}
}

class MommasBoy extends BaseClass {
    /* accessible in relatives */
    protected function abstract_protected() {
        return __METHOD__;
    }
    protected function concrete() {
        return __METHOD__;
    }
}

class LatchkeyKid extends BaseClass {
    function abstract_protected() {}
    public function __construct() {
        echo 'In ', __CLASS__, ":\n";
        $kid = new MommasBoy();
        echo $kid->abstract_protected(), "\n", $kid->concrete(), "\n";
    }
}

$obj = new LatchkeyKid();
```

Output:

> ```
> In LatchkeyKid: 
> MommasBoy::abstract_protected
> MommasBoy::concrete
> ```

If you ignore the warnings and declare magic methods (other than `__construct`, `__destruct` and `__clone`) as `protected`, they appear to be accessible in relatives, as with non-magic methods.

Protected `__clone` and `__destruct` are not accessible in relatives, whether or not they're abstract. This leads me to believe the behavior of abstract `__construct` is a bug.

```php
<?php
abstract class BaseClass {
    abstract protected function __clone();
}

class MommasBoy extends BaseClass {
    protected function __clone() {
        echo __METHOD__, "\n";
    }
}

class LatchkeyKid extends BaseClass {
    public function __construct() {
        echo 'In ', __CLASS__, ": \n";
        $kid = new MommasBoy();
        $kid = clone $kid;
    }
    public function __clone() {}
}

$obj = new LatchkeyKid();
```

Output:

> ```
> In LatchkeyKid:
>
> Fatal error: Call to protected MommasBoy::__clone() from context 'LatchkeyKid' in - on line 16
> ```

Access to `__clone` is enforced in [zend_vm_def.h](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/Zend/zend_vm_def.h?revision=322928&view=markup) (specifically, [`ZEND_CLONE`](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/Zend/zend_vm_def.h?revision=322928&view=markup#l3380) opcode handler). This is in addition to access checks for methods, which may be why it has different behavior. However, I don't see special treatment for accessing `__destruct`, so there's obviously more to it.

Stas Malyshev (hi, Stas!), one of the PHP developers, took a look into `__construct`, `__clone` and `__destruct` and had this to say:

> In general, function defined in base class should be accessible to all
>   [descendents] of that class. The rationale behind it is that if you define
>   function (even abstract) in your base class, you saying it will be
>   available to any instance (including extended ones) of this class. So
>   any descendant of this class can use it.
>
> [...] I checked why ctor behaves differently, and it's because parent ctor
>   is considered to be prototype for child ctor (with signature
>   enforcement, etc.) only if it's declared abstract or brought from the
>   interface. So, by declaring ctor as abstract or making it part of the
>   interface, you make it part of the contract and thus accessible to all
>   hierarchy. If you do not do that, ctors are completely unrelated to each
>   other (this is different for all other non-static methods) and thus
>   having parent ctor doesn't say anything about child ctor, so parent
>   ctor's visibility does not carry over. So for ctor is not a bug. [Note: this is similar to J. Bruni's answer.]
>
> I still think it's most probably a bug for __clone and __destruct.
>
> [...]
>
> I've submitted [bug #61782](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61782) to track the issue with __clone and __destruct.

Comment: protected properties are denied the access while in the mean time protected constructor is not!!.. ChildClass Object should not be instantiated in the first place!! according to PHP specs.

Comment: @Ahmad Think about it like this: `abstract` declarations separate the code between method **definition** and **implementation**. If you've ever worked with something like C header files you know the difference. The function *definition* defines the visibility. Properties cannot be declared `abstract`, so the comparison doesn't count.

Comment: @outis.. thanks for explaination, but still i don't get why PHP works that way:)..it only happens with abstract BaseClass that has abstract constructor. thats the only case, other wise instantiation fails. still I need to know why that happens, but thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 3):

Why it works?

Because from inside `ParentClass` you have granted access to the abstract method from `BaseClass`. It is this very same abstract method which is called from `ChildClass`, despite its implementation is defined on itself.

All relies in the difference between a concrete and an abstract method.

You can think like this: an abstract method is a single method with several implementations. On the other hand, each concrete method is a unique method. When it has the same name than its parent, it **overrides** the parent's one (it does not **implement** it).

So, when declared `abstract`, it is always the base class method which is called.

Think about a method declared `abstract`: Why the signatures of different implementations can't differ? Why can't the child classes declare the method with less visibility?

Anyway, you have just found a very interesting *feature*. Or, if my understanding above is not correct, and your expected behaviour is the truly expected behaviour, then you have found a bug.

Comment: Are you saying that irrelevant classes can instantiate each other just if they inherit the same abstract BaseClass with its constructor declared abstract,without any regard to the constructor signature of any SubClass?

Comment: How are these classes "irrelevant", they implement the same abstract class! Also, constructor signatures are the same (and they must be, because they implement the same abstract method). Anyway, I think this answer actually explains this behaviour, so you definitely may accept it.

Comment: @Snifff: Probably he meant "unrelated" instead of "irrelevant". Anyway, your comment still apply.

Comment: @AhmadFarouk: Yes, the signature at any subclass should be ignored - it MUST be the same as declared in the abstract class. It may be more visible. You think "visibility wins" while it seems "concreteness wins". The main point to consider is the difference between **override** (overload) versus **implement**.

Comment: Anyway, considering latest findings from user "outis", who researched PHP source code, I'm more inclined to consider it a "bug". In fact, it is up to the developers to decide, since we have good explanations for both behaviours. To you, one is clearly the "correct" and "expected" while the other is "bug". To me, both are reasonable. For me, they could change the behaviour to match your expactations, and this would be fine, too. Conclusion: it is a matter of **choice**, more than being a bug or not (not excluding the possibility of being a bug indeed).

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: constructors act differenlty... It's expected to work even without abstract classes but I found [this test](http://svn.osgeo.org/mapguide/sandbox/adsk/rfc79/Oem/php/Zend/tests/bug37632.phpt) that tests the same case and it looks like it's a technical limitation - the stuff explained below doesn't work with constructors right now.

<strike>There's no bug</strike>. You need to understand that access attributes work with objects' context. When you extend a class, your class will be able to see methods in BaseClass' context. ChildClass and ParentClass both in BaseClass context, so they can see all BaseClass  methods. Why do you need it? For polymorphism:

```
  class BaseClass {
     protected function a(){}
  }

  class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
    protected function a(){
      echo 'It works';
     }
  }

  class ParentClass extends BaseClass {
    public function b(BaseClass $a) {
      $a->a();
    }
    public function a() {

    }
  }
```

No matter what child you pass into ParentClass::b() method, you'll be able to access BaseClass methods (including protected, because ParentClass is BaseClass child and children can see protected methods of their parents). The same behaviour applies to <strike>constructors</strike> and abstract classes.

Comment: No actually, because according to my example, if the BaseClass is concrete and not abstract, object instantiation would fail.. according to your explaination, it should succeed both ways. it also fails if the BaseClass constructor is not abstract.. so that results in a very specific case, where the BaseClass is abstract, and its Constructor is also declared abstract

Comment: @AhmadFarouk you're right. But it should work without abstract classes but there's seems to be known issues with constructors context. Updated my answer.

Comment: According to my understanding, instantiation should fail whatever the case, since the ParentClass doesn't inherit a cent from the ChildClass.. Expected failure happens for all possible cases, except for the case we are discussing now

Comment: @AhmadFarouk I think there are two sides: 1) you don't want to allow instantiate a class with protected constructor from another 'not a direct child' class 2) on the other hand you want all methods to be consistent and act the same way. Anyway, abstract method or not shouldn't change a method's visibility - make a bug report.

Comment: @meze.. you got me right now.. Abstract method or not shouldn't alter the method access (visibility). so the protected Access modifier is the governing rule to allow or deny access, not the abstract declaration.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if there isn't something buggy w/ the abstract implementation under the hood, or if there is a subtle issue going on that we're missing.  Changing BaseClass from abstract to concrete produces the fatal error you're after though (classes renamed for my sanity)

EDIT: I agree w/ what @deceze is saying in his comments, that it is an edge case of abstract implementation and potentially a bug.  This is at least a work-around that provides the expected behavior albiet some ugly technique (feigned abstract base class).

```
class BaseClass
{
    protected function __construct()
    {
        die('Psuedo Abstract function; override in sub-class!');
    }
}

class ChildClassComposed extends BaseClass
{
    protected function __construct()
    {
        echo 'It works';
    }
}


// Child of BaseClass, Composes ChildClassComposed
class ChildClassComposer extends BaseClass
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        new ChildClassComposed();
    }
}
```

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to protected ChildClassComposed::__construct()
>   from context 'ChildClassComposer' in
>   /Users/quickshiftin/junk-php/change-private-of-another-class.php on
>   line 46

Comment: that's the fatal error I needed to happen. why it doesn't happen with the base class if declared abstract.. I really need an explanation to why PHP behaves in a different way with regard to abstract base classes than with concrete classes

Comment: Look at what everybody else is saying, including the other answer.  It's an edge case around using protected constructors in an abstract context.  Make sure you accept one of the answers and get that rate of yours heading in the right direction :D

Comment: What exactly *is* the "expected behavior"? The present behavior is arguably just as expectable. :)

Comment: @deceze Just getting the constructor of `ChildClassComposed` to raise a fatal when it's called from within `ChildClassComposer`, though I agree; current behavior is expected if you know what you're doing, lol.  Just trying to help OP get at _his_ desired behavior :)

Comment: I am not asking for a workaround.. I know dozens of workarounds.. I just need to know why things work that way with abstract classes. for my sanity too, I need explanation, or it will be a PHP bug.

Comment: @AhmadFarouk as your question on **internals@lists.php.net** to find out if it is a bug or not.